# Why $(A^x - (A-1)^x - (A+1)) \bmod A = 0$ when $x$ is a positive odd integer greater than $2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

Assuming that I am correct, Why $(A^x - (A-1)^x - (A+1)) \bmod A = 0$ when $x$ is a positive odd integer greater than $2$?

Examples:

$(7^3 - 6^3 -8) \bmod 7 = 0$ : $(343-216-8) / 7 = 119 / 7 =17$

$(11^3 - 10^3 -12) \bmod 11 = 0$ : $(1331-1000-12) / 11 = 319 / 11 = 29$

$(12^5 - 11^5 -13) \bmod 12 = 0$ : $(248832-161051-13) / 12 = 87768 / 12 = 7314$

$(13^7 - 12^7 -14) \bmod 13 = 0$ : $(62748517-35831808-14) / 13 = 26916695 / 13 = 2070515$

I know that:

When $x=2$ we have $A^2-(A-1)^2 = A + B$, and $(A^x - (A-1)^x - (A+1)) \bmod A = 0$ wouldn't work as in the following example:

$(5^2 - 4^2 - 6)  \bmod 5 ≠ 0$

When $x=3$ we have $A^3-(A-1)^3 = A^2 + (A-1)^2 + A(A-1)$:

Example:

$7^3-6^3 = 7^2+6^2 +7⋅6$

When $x=4$ we have $A^4-(A-1)^4 = A^3 + (A-1)^3 + (A+(A-1))(A(A-1))$:

Example:

$11^4-10^4 = 11^3+10^3 + (11+10)(11⋅10)$

...

So I am capable on getting some insight for the relationship between $A^x$ and $A^x-1$ as the result of $A^x-(A^x-1)$, but how come further subtracting by $(A+1)$ is divisible by $A$, such as: $(A^x - (A-1)^x - (A+1)) \bmod A = 0$ when $x$ is a positive odd integer greater than $2$?

If this is a duplicate, please close and refer me to the right place.  I tried searching but I don't even know what should I be searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^x - (a-1)^x - (a+1) \mod a$ \begin{align} &= {}_xC_1 a^{x-1}(-1)^2 + {}_xC_2 a^{x-2}(-1)^3 - ... + {}_xC_{x-1} a(-1)^x + (-1)^{x+1} - a - 1 \mod a \\ &= (-1)^{x+1} - 1 \mod a \end{align}
Now if $x$ is odd, the sum $\mod a$ is $1 - 1 = 0$.

And even if $x = 1$, we can more exlicitly find out the sum $\mod a$ to be $-a \Rightarrow 0$. So the statement you put forward is correct for all positive odd integers $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$A^x - (A-1)^x \equiv (-1)^{x+1} \mod A.$$ (expand using the binomial theorem), so your quantity equals $(-1)^{x+1} - 1$ modulo $A.$ But $x$ is odd, so the quantity equals to $0$.